# Is there any way to create logical image (.l01) in ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, disk, computer-forensics, diskimage

Is there any way to create logical image (l01) in Ubuntu.
i am trying it with FTK-Image but gives exe file. but i want to create it in Ubuntu system.

Comment: DO you want to create image of your harddisk?

Comment: yes,or is there way to create logical image with specific files  in my system.

Answer (score 0):

To create a image of your disk you can use command like:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/imagefile
```

If you want to create image of only one filesystem you can use:

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/path/to/imagefile
```

**NB! Do not write the image file in to the same disk/filesystem**

Comment: i tried it shows "dd: failed to open '/dev/sda3': No such file or directory"

Comment: aslo i tried with first command but it shows "dd: failed to open '/dev/sda': Permission denied"

Comment: @akki, those are examples to demonstrate the command. Feel free to change it according to your disks/partitions

Comment: @akki, it create raw image

Comment: then,how to create L01 ?

Comment: @akki, this is vendor specific format. So you should use vendor software. But check with the vendor if you can open raw images

Answer (score 0):

There is a CLI version of FTK that also runs on Ubuntu http://aaforensics.blogspot.com/2017/09/command-line-ftk-imager.html. Direct Download from [FTK](https://accessdata.com/product-download?/support/product-downloads) DEBIAN AND UBUNTU X64 – 3.1.1. There is also a Live-CD from Paladin where tools are integrated, which create a logical or physical image